# Delete images of different folders in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

I've saved images of posts in different sub-folders inside **public/images** like featured_image **(public/images/featured_image)**, **banner(public/images/banner)**. I want to delete images(featured_image and banner) related to post when banner is deleted.

This is my setup in `filesystem.php`

```
'local' => [
  'driver' => 'local',
  'root' => public_path('images/'),
],
```

I'm trying this to delete posts and images related to this:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    //
    $tour = Tour::find($id);
    $tour->country()->detach();
    Storage::delete('featured_image/$tour->featured_image');
    Storage::delete('banner/$tour->banner');
    $tour->delete();

    Session::flash('success', 'The tour is sucessfully deleted.');
    return redirect()->route('tours.index');
}
```

The post gets deleted successfully but the images are not deleted from the folder. Please suggest the possible solution.

Comment: Could be typo. The variables `$tour` in the `delete` function calls is not being interpreted as variables: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3446245/534862

Comment: If i do `Storage::delete('featured_image'/$tour->featured_image);
        Storage::delete('banner'/$tour->banner);` I get error cannot be divided by zero.

Comment: "Division by zero" because in this way you are doing a division on two strings! Strings are converted into 0 when it contains no numbers in it

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
Storage::delete('images/featured_image/' . $tour->featured_image);
Storage::delete('images/banner/' . $tour->banner);
```

If that doesn't work... you can also do.

```
$images = [
  'featured_image' => public_path('images/featured_image/' . $tour->featured_image),
  'banner_image' => public_path('images/banner/' . $tour->banner),
];

foreach($images as $image) {
  if(file_exists($image)) {
    unlink($image);
  }
}
```

Comment: Non of these above worked. First one returned error of unlink problem, second one gave error of unexpected '.' in line `'featured_image' => public_path('featured_image/' . $tour->featured_image);` I got it working by using File:delete() method.

Comment: @ZacharyDale The error was not with '.', but with ';' (semi-colon). Edited my code. I am damn sure this should work though. Also, I noticed I had given wrong path to the file. Update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by using `File:delete();` method.

```
public function destroy($id)
{

    $tour = Tour::find($id);
    $tour->country()->detach();
    File::delete(public_path('/images/featured_image/' . $tour->featured_image));
    File::delete(public_path('/images/banner/' . $tour->banner));
    $tour->delete();

    Session::flash('success', 'The tour is sucessfully deleted.');
    return redirect()->route('tours.index');
}
```